# Transfer contacts/messages from bada

Tags: contacts

I want to import contacts from bada OS to my windows phone. I do not want to copy them to sim. I want some sync method. I have tried a lot of things but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? Does Bada have a way to sync your contacts to a cloud service like Outlook.com or Gmail? Because if so, you can use that to get them to Windows Phone.

Comment: Messages are not transferable between most phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the answer.

I used Samsung Kies to export contacts in csv format.

Outlook uses a different csv format for its contacts so I arranged the contacts from bada in required form, and then uploaded to the outlook account.

Answer (score 0):

If your old phone has Bluetooth, then you can use the [Transfer my Data](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=dc08943b-7b3d-4ee5-aa3c-30f1a826af02) app which is available for (at least) all Nokia devices, and does a good job of importing contacts

Comment: i tried that.. It didn't work.

Comment: AFAIK, most of BADA OS phones are from Samsung. Might not support this.

Comment: @TanujWadhwa *What* didn't work about it?